# wordpress website making appointment into google calender

Tags: wordpress

I am working for a VZW with a website and would really like the functionality that the website user can book an appointment in their Google calendar and the VZW only has to confirm / cancel the appointment and it is added directly to the agenda. I have already found many plugins online to show a google agenda / calendar. But is it also possible to book an appointment?

Does anyone already have experience with this or does there see another viable solution?

Thanks in advance to anyone who wants to make the effort to help!